# Multi-column Rank in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, dense-rank

There probably is, but I'm slightly new to SQL Server.  I need to rank/denserank a dataset, but the ranking is based on 6 columns.  What I have at the moment is:

```
SELECT  col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col2 desc) as APPLICANT_RANK 
FROM    myTable
```

So that works fine, but if there is a tie in col2, then I get two records ranked the same.  What I want is if there's a tie in col2, to see the higher number in col3, then col4, so down the line to col 6.

Thanks

Comment: Please share some exaamples of what you are trying to achieve. the input   and the desired output

Comment: @Looking_for_answers what is unclear about this question?  Examples, input, and output are good *when needed to understand the problem*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include multiple columns in the `order by` clause in the rank function, just as you would when ordering the results of a whole query:

```
RANK() OVER(
   ORDER BY col2 desc,col3 desc, col4 desc, col5 desc, col6 desc
) as APPLICANT_RANK
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion it worked great.  I also found that I could interchange that Rank with ROW_Number and achieved the same result.

Comment: @NYBrummie . . . They only produce the same result if you never have duplicates above the size columns.